# Error implementing NextAuth credentials with custom login and backend

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, next-auth

I am implementing NextAuth with my NextJS(GraphQL) app. I have this error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'credentials' in null
```

The network error also shows:

**Error: HTTP GET is not supported for /api/auth/session**

**Error: HTTP GET is not supported for /api/auth/providers**

I am not making a `GET` request anywhere I know. My code is below:

`pages/api/[...nextauth.js]`

```
const providers = [
  Providers.Credentials({
    name: 'Credentials',
    authorize: async (credentials) => {
      try {
        const user = await <GraphQL Logic to fetch user>

        if (user) {
          return {status: 'success', data: user.data.user}
        } 
      } catch (e) {
        const errorMessage = e.response.data.message
        // Redirecting to the login page with error messsage in the URL
        throw new Error(errorMessage + '&email=' + credentials.email)
      }

    }
  })
]

const callbacks = {
  async jwt(token, user) {
    if (user) {
      token.accessToken = user.data.token
    }

    return token
  },

  async session(session, token) {
    session.accessToken = token.accessToken
    return session
  }
}

const options = {
  providers,
  callbacks,
  pages: {
    error: '/login' // Changing the error redirect page to our custom login page
  }
}

export default (req, res) => NextAuth(req, res, options)
```

`pages/login.js`

```
<form onSubmit={(e) => handleLogin(e)}>
            <input value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
            <input type='password' value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
            <button type='submit' disabled={isLoginStarted}>Log In</button>
          </form>
```

`handleLogin method`

```
const handleLogin = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setIsLoginStarted(true)
    signIn('credentials',
      {
        email,
        password,
        callbackUrl: `${window.location.origin}/welcome`
      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: Could you solve the problem?

Comment: I have same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Why the URL look like that

```
pages/api/[...nextauth.js]
```

it must be

```
pages/api/[...nextauth].js
```

or if you are using next.js 13.4, then

```
pages/api/[...nextauth]/route.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Signin method takes in a `provider id` as its first argument. Therefore, all methods are called for a specific provider.
In your case you are calling a signin method for provider `credentials` but in your configuration, there is no provider with id `credentials`.

To fix this, set `id: 'credentials'` in your credentials provider config:

```
const providers = [
  Providers.Credentials({
    id: 'credentials',
    name: 'Credentials',
    authorize: async (credentials) => {
      try {
        const user = await <GraphQL Logic to fetch user>

        if (user) {
          return {status: 'success', data: user.data.user}
        } 
      } catch (e) {
        const errorMessage = e.response.data.message
        // Redirecting to the login page with error messsage in the URL
        throw new Error(errorMessage + '&email=' + credentials.email)
      }

    }
  })
]
```